# Why does \color{blue} after \paragraph{...} color the paragraph title blue?

Tags: color, sections-paragraphs

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Why am I blue?}

{\color{blue} Only I am supposed to be blue!}

\end{document}
```

Output (plus my scribble):

[image]

**Question**: Why does `\color{blue}` after `\paragraph{...}` color the paragraph title blue?

There's a workaround by replacing `\paragraph{...}` with `\paragraph{\color{black} ...}`, but this does not seem like desirable behaviour.

Comment: Add `\leavevmode` before the color command, or use \textcolor{blue}{text} instead of \color.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\paragraph` is set at the start of the next paragraph. The next paragraph starts with the first letter `O` of `Only` *after* `\color{blue}`.

Fixes:

- `\leavevmode` to explicitly start the paragraph before the color change:

  ```
  \paragraph{Why am I blue?}
  \leavevmode
  {\color{blue} Only I am supposed to be blue!}
  ```
- `\textcolor` to limit the scope of the color setting:

  ```
  \paragraph{Why am I blue?}
  \textcolor{blue}{Only I am supposed to be blue!}
  ```

The result in both cases with updated text:

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 14):

To complement Heiko’s (as usual) fine answer, some more words about the workings of `\paragraph`.

The command is defined in terms of `\@startsection` with a certain set of parameters, one of which is taken as the given title; one of the parameters tells LaTeX that the heading should be typeset inline, so the title is momentarily stored away.

It will be reinserted when the *following* paragraph starts. This allows a more free syntax: the input

```
\paragraph{Title} Some text
```

produces the same result as

```
\paragraph{Title}

Some text
```

and adding a `\label` after `\paragraph{Title}` doesn't insert unwanted spaces.

In both cases, `\paragraph{Title}` doesn't start a (text) paragraph (the unfortunate name clash might be distracting). The next paragraph start is triggered by `S` (it could also be `\indent`, `\noindent`, `\leavevmode` or `\hspace`, essentially what the TeXbook calls a *horizontal command*).

When TeX sees this `S` it backs it up, inserts parskip glue and the indentation box. After this it inserts whatever has been stored away, which is not only the title, but also

1. instructions to remove the indentation box;
2. the stored title, possibly preceded or followed by the paragraph number;
3. instructions for correct spacing the title from the following text and for avoiding that a page break occurs immediately following the line with the title.

In particular, the title is inserted as part of the current (text) paragraph. After this the `S` that triggered the action is reinserted back and TeX continues reading the text for later break it into lines.

In your case the *horizontal command* is `O`, which is already under the scope of `\color{blue}`, so also the title is typeset blue.

As a general rule, avoid `\color` before starting a (text) paragraph.

Instead of the arcane `\leavevmode` you can also use `\indent`, `\noindent` or `\hspace{0pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Test}

{\color{blue}XXXX}

\paragraph{Test}

\indent{\color{blue}XXXX}

\paragraph{Test}

\noindent{\color{blue}XXXX}

\paragraph{Test}

\hspace{0pt}{\color{blue}XXXX}

\paragraph{Test}

\leavevmode{\color{blue}XXXX}

\paragraph{Test}

\textcolor{blue}{XXXX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. For the sake of the completeness, remembering my own confusions when I was starting, just add that the horizontal mode start also with  several  commands that could have invisible results as `\mbox{}`, `\makebox{}` , `\rule{0pt}{0pt}` or `${}$`, and using xelatex/lualatex even a invisible character (also in the source code) as the zero width character,  u+200b (one can go crazy when is not aware of this). But  many others as `\hphantom{}` or `\hbox{}` have not this result (do not be fooled by the "h" of these commands).

Comment: @Fran Yes, also `\mbox{}` would do, because it starts doing `\leavevmode`; on the other hand `${}$` is not necessarily invisible, because of `\mathsurround`. I generally avoid abusing math mode unless necessary.

Comment: Same here. In fact, when prefer the arcane and longer  `\leavevmode` over any short trick because nonetheless is self-explanatory  (once you know what mean) while, for instance, I find harder a forensic analysis  of  what the hell I did  yesterday if there a empty box somewhere in a macro.